# Should I pull to another job workspace or should I push from it the 2nd job dependencies?

Tags: continuous-integration, deployment, dependencies, continuous-delivery, jenkins

I have a question regarding CI/CD procedure. I do have 2 Jenkins jobs, the 1st one will build a binary file who is a dependency to the 2nd job build successfully.

Should I push this binary from 1st job to the 2nd one or should I pull this binary from 1st job to the 2nd one?

*I'm **NOT** talking about Git here...*

Basically:

1) Push -> 1st pushes binary to 2nd job when it's done

2) Pull -> 2nd pull the binary from 1st job when its starts

I think the CD would cover the option 1) but at same time I think the 2nd job must be in charge to get all your dependencies and be able to build atomicly.

Comment: Can you put it in some kind of artefact repo so that the 2nd job (and anything else that needs it) can get it from there?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's a good point, actually now I don't have such a infra for that but could be a good approach in the near future...

Comment: You could also have the 1st job just trigger the 2nd one on success, but leave the 2nd job pull the artifact itself as a dependency. To me pushing feels a bit awkward and adds an unnecessary step to the 1st build which isn't really critical for its primary job.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling it could make it easier to manage in the future and extensible.

- You can decide what to do If the pulled binary was not found.
- Imagine having multiple pipelines pushing. You would want even more flexibility on what to do in each receiving pipeline, you would then need to send additional related information for the `consumer`(2nd pipeline). The `consumer` part should not depend on the incoming instructions but know  what it should do with possible inputs.

Answer (score 0):

imo, this partly depends on how the second job is set up and how long your whole Pipeline takes to finish.

If time is not a concern then 1) would be a natural approach.
If time is a problem and Job 2) can start some work without needing the dependency you could try to optimate here.

Comment: I don't think your answer addresses the push vs. pull concern